# Using both subdirectory and subdomains in Multisite

Tags: multisite, subdomains

Am I able to use both subdirectories and subdomains for separate sites in Multisite?

For example:

- example.com - Main site
- uk.example.com - site for the UK
- uk.example.com/London - site for London, UK

Can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into something like [WP Multi Network](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**, Multisite uses the domain name to determine which site you are on, so there is no way to set up a Multisite site in a subfolder.

Having said that, depending on what you want to achieve there's often ways around it.

For example, if you were ok with using a separate WordPress installation for the subfolder site, you could create the subfolder manually, set up WordPress in it, and there you have it - alongside your main Multisite install in the root. Of course, this could get messy if you have *a lot* of these subsites, and again, it really depends on your goals.

In the end, anything is possible with enough time and resources, but from the information you've provided so far it sounds like it's not *easily* possible with the default way Multisite works.